# C++ Abstract Classes and Inheritance

Tags: c++, oop, abstract-class

I have this problem I'm trying to solve. Basically the base class has the function map, which takes a vector as input and outputs the final vector after some mapping function, in this case - f, has been performed. However, I'm really lost as to why when I print out 2*testVector - test1 in the main function, I get proper output, i.e. 6, -182 etc... but when I print out 2*testVector - test 2, it's still the same vector.

This happens both when I create "DoubleElements" twice or just call the same "DoubleElements" pointer twice (it only ever performs 1 map). Am I fundamentally missing some understanding? Any help is appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class RecursiveBase {
public: 
vector<int> map(vector<int> baseVector) {
    static int iter = 0;
     // Base case, return the final vector. 
    if (iter == 5) {
        return baseVector;
    // Replace the element with the old element mapped to the function.
    } else {
        baseVector[iter] = this->f(baseVector[iter]);
        iter++;
        return map(baseVector);
    }
}

private:
    virtual int f(int value) = 0;
};

class DoubleElements: public RecursiveBase {
private:
    int f(int value) {
        return 3*value;
    }
};

int main() {
    vector<int> testVector, o1, o2;
    testVector.push_back(3);
    testVector.push_back(-91);
    testVector.push_back(-42);
    testVector.push_back(-16);
    testVector.push_back(13);

    DoubleElements de;
    DoubleElements de1;

    RecursiveBase *test1 = &de;
    RecursiveBase *test2 = &de1;

    o1 = test1->map(testVector);
    o2 = test2->map(testVector);

    std::cout << "2*testVector - test1" << std::endl;
    for (unsigned int iter = 0; iter < o1.size(); iter++) {
        std::cout << o1[iter] << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "2*testVector - test2" << std::endl;
    for (unsigned int iter = 0; iter < o2.size(); iter++) {
        std::cout << o2[iter] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's because your variable is static and thus shared among all instances of class `RecursiveBase`. So when you calculate map for `o1`, `iter` will be incremented to five. and when you calculate for `o2`, iter is already five and thus the same vector (`baseVector`) will be returned immediately

Comment: You're missing an `override` for f() in your child class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static int iter = 0;
```

You should avoid declaring local static variables in methods unless 100% necessary.

The first call will increment `iter` to 5, but on the next call, `iter`, since it's static, will not reset it's value to 0.

As an example, a simple program like:

```
void test()
{
    static int x = 0;
    ++x;    
    cout << x << endl;
}

int main()
{        
    test();
    test();    
    return 0;
}
```

Will output

```
1
2
```

Comment: Thanks a heap, this makes a lot of sense now, I thought I was totally missing something about abstract classes.

Comment: Remember to mark the answer as correct if it answered your question c:

Answer (score 1):

From [class.static.data/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.static.data#1):

> A static data member is not part of the subobjects of a class.

For `iter` is `static`. It is part of the `class RecursiveBase` **NOT** part of the `RecursiveBase` objects.

To fix it, reset `iter` to `0`:

```
if (iter == 5) {
   iter = 0; // reset iter
   return baseVector;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
2*testVector - test1
9
-273
-126
-48
39
2*testVector - test2
9
-273
-126
-48
39
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only ever call `RecursiveBase::map` *once* as it stands, because the `iter` is static. You also assume that you will only ever call it with a 5 element `std::vector<int>`, at which point `std::array<int, 5>` is a better choice.

If you want a recursive solution, instead pass the index as an additional parameter

```
public:
std::vector<int> map(std::vector<int> vec) {
    return do_map(vec, 0);
}
private:
std::vector<int> do_map(std::vector<int> & vec, std::size_t index) {
    if (index == vec.size()) { return vec; }
    vec[index] = f(vec[index]);
    return do_map(vec, ++index);
}
```

But that's still a gratuitous use of recursion. A much better solution is

```
public:
std::vector<int> map(std::vector<int> vec) {
    std::transform(vec.begin(), vec.end(), vec.begin(), [this](int i) { return f(i); });
    return vec;
}
```

You also have superfluous `RecursiveBase *` in your main

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> testVector{3, -91, -42, -16, 13};

    DoubleElements de;
    DoubleElements de1;

  // declare at point of initialisation
  // don't need ->
    auto o1 = de.map(testVector);
    auto o2 = de1.map(testVector);

    std::cout << "2*testVector - test1" << std::endl;
    for (unsigned int iter = 0; iter < o1.size(); iter++) {
        std::cout << o1[iter] << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "2*testVector - test2" << std::endl;
    for (unsigned int iter = 0; iter < o2.size(); iter++) {
        std::cout << o2[iter] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for feedback, unfortunately since it is for an assignment, it has to be recursion, but the solution you offered is 10x more readable and logical. Cheers

Comment: The more I look at it, the more I think `RecursiveBase` is a class masquerading as `std::transform`. Does your instructor think all functions must belong to a class?

Comment: Yes that's correct, mostly a tonne of smaller classes implementing different mapping functions like square rooting, tripling, another whole set of classes for filtering a vector. So for map it has to be like: MapBaseClass from which MapSquareRoot inherits etc.

Comment: uggh... `[this](int i) { return f(i); }` defines an instance of a class (which has no name), with a single method. In C++ you don't need a run-time polymorphic hierarchy *most* of the time, and when you do, there already exists `std::function<...>`

Comment: I'm curious and want to learn more, do you know of any good resources on *proper* oop practices/programming practices in c++. I'm finding it a bit ridiculous that I have 22 .cpp and .h files combined to implement only 8 functions using the inheritance structure...

Comment: There's [the definitive book list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/2610810). Note that C++ is multi-paradigm, OO isn't the be-all end-all, although if you take the C++ definition of "object" pedantically, everything is an object, and free-functions can be thought of as members of a "static namespace object"